# In $http.get how do i match dynamic page id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

```
dhmsApp.controller('dhmsDetailsView',function($scope,$http, $routeParams){
    console.log($routeParams.id);
    $http.get("include/detailViewBg.php").success(function (response) {$scope.names = response});
});
```

I'm getting id in controller i.e `$routeParams.id`, but my problem is how i will match `$routeParams.id` in `$http.get()` .

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by *match*?

Comment: Match means : i want to pass $routeParams.id into detailViewBg.php
so that i can invoke it into SQL where condition

Comment: `$http.get("include/detailViewBg.php", {params: {id: $routeParams.id}})` Is this what you need?

Comment: In what format your endpoint accepts data? JSON or query string?

Comment: Yes,

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT pages, main_id FROM dhms_index_table where main_id='"+ ? +"'");

above sql query is in detailViewBg.php

and in where condition i marked as  Question mark what parameter should i pass.

Comment: Yes it accept in JSON

Comment: @Harshad With my previous comment you can get the parameter on the server using `$_GET['id']`, but you code is not safe and exposed to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - You should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: @Alon Eitan 
yes i will change to MySQLi ... Thank you very much for suggestion.
 I store $_GET['id'] in 1 variable and i invoke that variable in SQL query wehere condition...

but it is showing some error

Comment: error is angular.js:10071Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]

Comment: It doesn't look like a problem coming from the server, but from one of the `ng-repeat`in your view. You should add `track by $index` (https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes)

Comment: @Alon Eitan 
can you please share me your email id

Comment: @Alon Eitan : Thank you.. above suggestion worked for me !!! :)